# Linking to a network directory using Rmarkdown

Tags: r, r-markdown

I'm creating an Rmarkdown and I would like to have a link pointing to a network drive.

When I type the following `[path](\\\\network_drive\\data\\raw_files)` and subsequently knit to .pdf, the link is 'translated' into \\network_drive\data\raw_files.pdf in my document.

How can I avoid the .pdf suffix from the link, since I'd like to point to a directory and not to an individual file?

Answer (score 0):

wouldn't you just want to do

`[path](\\\\network_drive\\data\\`

have you tried going into your Operating system file folder options and deselecting "file extension" to not display